# Update query with modal Bootstrap get undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, undefined-index

I'm trying to finish my new personal CMS(Content Management System) and i have programmed one section which includes insert, select and delete item in one page with PHP, MySql and bootstrap Modal.
obviously i have trouble with update query. The process is when i click on edit button, modal Bootstrap will show up, Then associate data will retrieve form Mysql by value attribute. after than i change them and click on submit button. The problem is here! When process complete there are errors form my $_POST['input_result']. the var_dump get NULL, and finally i have undefined index.
Is there anybody to figure out this problem??? Thank you all.
here is my modal Bootstrap code with PHP :

```
<?php
    $selectForUpdate = "SELECT * FROM ring WHERE id='4'";
    $resultSelectForUpdate = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $selectForUpdate);

    $first = $second = $third= '';
    $first = $_POST['u_ringCode'];
    $second = $_POST['u_ringWeight'];
    $third = $_POST['u_ringComment'];

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE ring SET ring_code='".$first."', ring_weight='".$second."', ring_comment='".$third."' WHERE id='4'";
    $resultUpdateQuery = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $updateQuery);
    while ( $showUpdateRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultSelectForUpdate ) ) {
?>
    <!-- Update Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="update-4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-4-label" >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="update-4-label" style="color:#ddd;" >
                        Edit Code
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <form method="post" action="<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Ring Code :</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="u_ringCode" placeholder="" value="<?=$showUpdateRows['ring_code']?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Ring Weight :</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="u_ringWeight" placeholder="" value="<?=$showUpdateRows['ring_weight']?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Comment :</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="u_ringComment" placeholder="" value="<?=$showUpdateRows['ring_comment']?>">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left" name="ringDelete" style="color:black;" href="?update=4">Submit</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: why are you not  using submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    /*Code Start For Connnect Database*/
        $connect_to_db=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_name" );
    /*Code End For Connnect Database*/
    /*Code Start For Update Modal Form*/
        if (isset($_REQUEST['ringUpdate'])) {
            $first = $_POST['u_ringCode'];
            $second = $_POST['u_ringWeight'];
            $third = $_POST['u_ringComment'];
            $updateQuery = "UPDATE ring SET ring_code='".$first."', ring_weight='".$second."', ring_comment='".$third."' WHERE id='4'";
            $resultUpdateQuery = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $updateQuery);
        }
    /*Code End For Update Modal Form*/
        $selectForUpdate = "SELECT * FROM ring WHERE id='4'";
        $resultSelectForUpdate = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $selectForUpdate);
            while ( $showUpdateRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultSelectForUpdate ) ) {

?>
    <!-- Update Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="update-4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-4-label" >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="post" action="<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="update-4-label" style="color:#ddd;" >
                    Edit Code
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Ring Code :</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="u_ringCode" placeholder="" value="<?=$showUpdateRows['ring_code']?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Ring Weight :</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="u_ringWeight" placeholder="" value="<?=$showUpdateRows['ring_weight']?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Comment :</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="u_ringComment" placeholder="" value="<?=$showUpdateRows['ring_comment']?>">
                        </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left" name="ringUpdate" style="color:black;" value="submit">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: It works buddy! Thank you very much. I hope you get best thinks which you want :D

Comment: Thanx, I am very Happy to Help You

Answer (score 0):

Your $_POST variable is empty before form submitting. You need to check this. Also it is not safe way to make db queries without escaping string. You can read more about this with searching MySQL-injections. And third thing you are getting items before update query. In this case you will see not changed data on your page.Only after page refresh it will show new values.
First part of your code could look like this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['u_ringCode'])&&!empty($_POST['u_ringWeight'])&&!empty($_POST['u_ringComment']))
{
    $first = $connect_to_db->escape_string($_POST['u_ringCode']);
    $second = $connect_to_db->escape_string($_POST['u_ringWeight']);
    $third = $connect_to_db->escape_string($_POST['u_ringComment']);
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE ring SET ring_code='$first', ring_weight='$second', ring_comment='$third' WHERE id='4'";
    $resultUpdateQuery = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $updateQuery);
}
$selectForUpdate = "SELECT * FROM ring WHERE id='4'";
$resultSelectForUpdate = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $selectForUpdate);


while ( $showUpdateRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultSelectForUpdate ) ) {
    ?>
```